# How to change tab separated file into CSV or semicolon separated file?

Tags: excel, csv

table:
t/s  s_1/m  x(t)

0,0 -0,2500 0,0

0,1 -0,2435 0,0

0,2 -0,2213 0,0

0,3 -0,1845 0,0

0,4 -0,1343 0,0

0,5 -0,0742 0,0

0,6 -0,0085 0,0

0,7 0,0575 0,0

I'm using excel and matlab (if that's important). In excel the data is in one single column instead of in 3 different columns and I don't know how to change that. I tried text import wizard in excel, but it didn't work, as nothing changed regarding the way the data is listed.

Im a beginner at programming and would be grateful for advise!

Comment: Is data format correct or should it have `.` instead of `,`?

Comment: Excel should be able to read CSV files with tab separators. Anyway, why tag MATLAB? You don’t mention it in the post, I don’t see the relation. Please use only relevant tags!

Comment: I mean obviously I need a CSV file in order for matlab to read it else it doesn't work for my task and the way the data is displayed is not of any use because its wrong formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, highlight the column of data, then

- In the `Data` tab click "Text to Columns"

  [image: text to columns button]
- Select "Delimited" for your data type
- Select "Tab" and/or "Space" as appropriate

  [image: text to columns dialog]
- Click Finish. The output is as shown:

  [image: result]

If you're writing to Excel from MATLAB then there will definitely be a way to write the data such that this isn't required, but without an example of your data generation/writing in MATLAB this is the best we can offer...